# Hide Row if value in checkbox greater than zero

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a table that is using calculated fields coming from 3 different tables in 2 distinct databases. I am trying to use a checkbox to hide the rows that have the calculated field greater than zero or students who owe money. I have added a checkbox with a value of zero.

```
<form id="formFilter" name="formFilter" method="post" action="">
  <p>
    <input name="selView" type="checkbox" id="selView" onChange="formFilter.submit()" 
value="0" <?php echo (isset($_POST['selView'])?'checked':'');?> />
    view only students with a balance<br />
  </p>
</form>
```

I need to evaluate $balancez and if $balancez is greater than zero, when I click the checkbox I want the rows of students who do not have a number greater than zero to hide. This way I can only view the students who have a balance owed.

```
<table width="800" border="0" class="TFtable sortable">
  <tr>
    <td scope="row"><strong>Students</strong> (<?php echo $totalRows_Recordset1 ?>)</td>
    <td align="center"><strong>ID</strong></td>
    <td align="center"><strong>Division</strong></td>
    <td align="center"><strong>AP Fee</strong></td>
    <td align="center"><strong>Credit Card Payment</strong></td>
    <td align="center"><strong>Store Payment</strong></td>
    <td align="center"><strong>AP Balance</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <?php do { ?>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row"><a href="student_report.php?recordID=<?php echo $row_Recordset1['ID']; ?>" target="new"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Student']; ?></a></td>
      <td align="center"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['ID']; ?></td>
      <td align="center"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Division']; ?></td>
      <td align="center"><?php echo "$".$row_Recordset1['Total']; ?></td>
      <td align="center"><?php



mysql_select_db($database_cc, $cc);
$studentid = $row_Recordset1['ID'];
$query_Recordset_CC = 'SELECT credit_card_activity.Student_ID, SUM(credit_card_activity.CC_Amount) AS total_cc2,  credit_card_activity.Ref_ID, credit_card_activity.Settle_Date FROM credit_card_activity WHERE credit_card_activity.Ref_ID LIKE "AP%" AND credit_card_activity.Student_ID = "'.$studentid.'" GROUP BY credit_card_activity.Student_ID';
$Recordset_CC = mysql_query($query_Recordset_CC, $cc) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset_CC = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset_CC);
$totalRows_Recordset_CC = mysql_num_rows($Recordset_CC);
$total_cc =-1*(0+$row_Recordset_CC['total_cc2']);


echo ($total_cc < 0 ? "($".abs($total_cc).")" : "$".$total_cc);


?></td>
      <td align="center"><?php



mysql_select_db($database_cc, $cc);
$studentid = $row_Recordset1['ID'];
$query_Recordset_Store = "SELECT checkout.student_id, SUM(`transaction`.total_amount) AS total_store2 FROM checkout, `transaction`, school_store WHERE `transaction`.activity_id=school_store.Tag AND `transaction`.transaction_id=checkout.transaction_id AND (`transaction`.refund_status='0' OR `transaction`.refund_status='1') AND school_store.Activity LIKE 'AP Fee%' AND checkout.student_id='".$studentid."' AND checkout.payment_type NOT IN ('Cash Refund') GROUP BY checkout.student_id";
$Recordset_Store = mysql_query($query_Recordset_Store, $cc) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset_Store = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset_Store);
$totalRows_Recordset_Store = mysql_num_rows($Recordset_Store);
$total_store = -1*(0+$row_Recordset_Store['total_store2']);

echo ($total_store < 0 ? "($".abs($total_store).")" : "$".$total_store);


?></td>
      <td align="center"><?php 
      $ap_fees=$row_Recordset1['Total'];
      $ap_cc=$row_Recordset_CC['total_cc2'];
      $ap_store=$row_Recordset_Store['total_store2'];
      $paid=$ap_cc + $ap_store;
      $balancez=($ap_fees - $paid);
      echo ($balancez < 0 ? "($".$balancez.")" : "$".$balancez);
      ?>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); 



    ?>
</table>
```

What makes this task difficult for me is that it is not based on a mysql query but on a calculated value ($balancez) based on other queries so I can't use Having. Can someone lead me to a jquery that can evaluate $balancez of each row and hide or display the row if value from checkbox is met? I am also open to any method that will solve this issue. Many thanks.

Comment: using jQuery, you can access the value of an input through `var inputvalue = parseFloat($("#yourbalance<?php echo"$balancekey"; ?>").val());` then evaluate it `if(inputvalue >= whatever_your_value_is) { /* do or do not ! there is no try */ }`

Comment: I would need much more hand holding on your solution. Can you provide a more complete solution?